# Distribute two SELECTs with a given ratio

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with the following data

table "group1":

```
id  | sequenceNo
----+-----------
101 | 1
102 | 2
103 | 3
104 | 4
105 | 5
```

table "group2":

```
id  | sequenceNo
----+-----------
201 | 1
202 | 2
203 | 3
204 | 4
205 | 5
```

I have a given ration of 3:1 which should build a mix of the groups.

The result would be:

```
id
--
101
102
103
201
104
105
```

Ideally the mixing stops when one of the groups is empty.

I've implemented a solution for the problem as an OO-program. However, 
I am curious if there is also a simple SQL-only solution.

Many thanks,

Maik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UNION ALL the 2 tables, but in the 2nd table's select, you should multiply the SequenceNo column by 3. (perhaps 3.00001, if you want it to show AFTER the third one of the first column).

**Solution:**

```
    SELECT * FROM 
     (SELECT id, SequenceNo FROM Group1
       UNION ALL
     SELECT id, SequenceNo*3.00001 FROM Group2)
   ORDER BY SequenceNo ASC
```

Comment: A where clause should be added to filter group2

Comment: That's neat. I knew something simple would exist.

Comment: Just for curiosity: If the ratio wouldn't be fixed but varying like 3:2 or 1:1, do you see a similar straight forward solution? Thanks!

Comment: yes of course: just change the *3.00001 to the ratio you want to use. you can even do: SequenceNo*((3/2)+0.00001)) (in this sample, 3/2 is for the ratio 3:2).

Comment: I eventually tried your later suggestion with the non-fixed ratio: however it does not work as expected: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64b8e/6/0   Anyway, you've answered the initial question correctly so I will tag this as being answered. Maybe you find some time to have a look at the fiddle though? Tnx!

Comment: Hi samba, you specified in your query you want a 3/2 ratio (i.e. 1.5 ratio), but you actually want aaa,bb type of ratio. I think you need to work with a mod formula for this. my idea still works; you just need to work out how to calculate the sequence number multiplier...